# PHP: replacing contents of multidimensional Arrays

Tags: php, session, multidimensional-array

We have a multi-dimensional array which consists of the following model:

> array(   0 => array('sfa' => 'sfb,'sfb' => 'aaaa,'sfc' => 'bbbb','sfd' =>
>   '10','sfe' => 'abc'),  1 =>  array('sfa' => 'sfb,'sfb' => 'aaaa,'sfc' =>
>   'bbbb','sfd' => '10','sfe' => 'abc'),  2 =>  array('sfa' => 'sfb,'sfb' =>
>   'aaaa,'sfc' => 'bbbb','sfd' => '10','sfe' => 'abc'),  3 =>  array('sfa' =>
>   'sfb,'sfb' => 'aaaa,'sfc' => 'bbbb','sfd' => '10','sfe' => 'abc'), )

please note this is an example.

This information is stored in a session variable however for example this session is called a so the variable is $_SESSION['a']

i need to be able to change the $_SESSION data for $_SESSION['a'][0]['sfd'] from 10 to 100

i have already tried the following code:

> $array = $_SESSION['a']; $quantity = 100; $replacements = array('sdf'
>   => $quantity); array_replace($array[0],$replacements);
>   var_dump($array);

But it won't work and it destroys the rest of the array aswel, I have tried but failed can anybody correct my mistake or give me a helping hand?

Comment: why not just set your variable directly?

    $_SESSION['a'][0]['sfd'] = 100;

Comment: this is to be changed after the session is set (editing quantity for example)

Comment: oh dear, That simple i completely overlooked that option!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i'm not sure if i got your point but is this what are you looking for ?

```
if (isset($_SESSION['a'][0]['sfd'] ))
    $_SESSION['a'][0]['sfd'] =100;
```

Comment: glad that i could help sir,

Comment: Small note: if you want to check existance here, you have to check each dimension individually.

Comment: no sir, isset will check each at once, if one of them is not set for example index `a` it will return false only

Comment: Wow, didnt know that. Tnx!